# How to get Windows Azure Biztalk Services SDK in Visual Studio 2013 RTM?

Tags: azure, biztalk

How to get Windows Azure Biztalk Services SDK working on Visual Studio 2013 RTM?

When I try to install it ask for Visual Studio 2012. Does it support VS2013 RTM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think WABS (Windows Azure BizTalk Services) SDK is ready for Visual Studio 2013. You probably need to wait. Since there is always a dependency between the tools (VS,SQL, Windows) and BizTalk (or even BizTalk Services SDK in this case), typically there will be a delay in supporting the latest developer tools.

Comment: Yes but there is always workarounds and also, BT SDK does nothing more than a project template and tollbar components so I dont think it is actually impossible. I did myself installed the SDK for VS2010 on 2012 pretty fine...

Comment: It's now 2016 and there still isn't support for VS2013 let alone 2015, which I am currently using.  So in order to use the SDK, I would need to install an IDE that is 4 years old.

Comment: @ewahner - agreed and greetings from the future.  It's nearly **2017** and we still have to use VS2012 to create a WABS.  Argh